# Searching HTML Files using Regex

Tags: c++, regex, qt, html-parsing

I have a pool of html files and want to search through them for same targeted text. It is required to search in their text contents only while ignoring all html tags, header, script, etc.

I tried QRegExp, the regex class in Qt, but could not find a good pattern to do what I'm after.

I’d appreciate any help in this regard.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 seems almost obligatory to link to

Comment: `if (question.contains '/(X|HT)ML/' and question.contains 'regex') add_comment('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/#1732454')`

Comment: @Tim Sylvester: Good point - except your regex could use a little work; it should really match "xhtml" as well.

Comment: @Jerry It does, 'xhtml' contains 'html'!  I guess I left off the `/i` but it is pseudo-code after all.

Comment: @Tim Sylvester: Okay, sounds reasonable... :-)

Comment: I really don't want to parse. Just want to remove anything between < and > then search in the remaining. Cannot regex do this?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be a good answer for you, but have you considered using a DOM-parser instead? That will eliminate the need to filter out what is text and what is HTML markup. Sadly I can't recommend a good one for C++ though.